# JS Reduce with parent parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to solve my last issue with my reduce function to turn a nested JSON object into a flat list to enable easier searching.

Taking the JSON Below

```
    {
  "MovementPatterns": [
    {
      "Id": "",
      "Name": "Warm-up",
      "Exercises": [
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Lizard Stretch",
          "Level": 1,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Pigeon Stretch",
          "Level": 1,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Core Hold",
          "Level": 1,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Superman",
          "Level": 1,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Horizontal Push",
      "Id": "",
      "Exercises": [
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Wall Push-up",
          "Level": 0,
          "VideoUrl": "",
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Push-up",
          "Level": 1,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Tap Push-up",
          "Level": 2,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Explosive Push-up",
          "Level": 3,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used the following code:

```
const exercises = data.MovementPatterns.reduce(
  (a, {Exercises}) => [...a, ...Exercises, ...a],
  [],
);
```

To flattern all the exercises from each movement pattern into a pure list of exercises...This is great, but I now need to INCLUDE in that JSON for each exercise the PARENT Movement Pattern ID  e.g.

```
[
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Lizard Stretch",
          "Level": 1,
          "MovementPatternId": 1,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
....
        {
          "Id": "",
          "Name": "Wall Push-up",
          "Level": 1,
          "MovementPatternId": 2,
          "EquipmentRequired": ""
        },
]
```

Can someone please help me figure out how to do this with my reduce function :)

Thanks

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Really helpful...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost close. Just append parent's `Id` as `MovementPatternId` to the each element of `Exercises`.

```
const exercises = ab.MovementPatterns.reduce(
  (a, { Exercises, Id }) => [
    ...a,
    ...Exercises.map(e => ({ ...e, MovementPatternId: Id }))
  ],
  []
);
```